# The COntrol of the program does not enter the for loop

Tags: c#

Here i am pasting the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace star1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Myclass obj = new Myclass();
            obj.getData();
            obj.pattern();
        }
    }
    class Myclass
    {
        int i, n, j;

        public void getData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program for displaying pattern of *.");
            Console.Write("Enter the maximum number of *: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public void pattern()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPattern 1 - Left Aligned:\n");
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)  // The Control does not enter the for loop
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                    Console.Write("*");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: beside that this is not a very clean piece of codes (style), which values did you try?

Comment: Does the words "Pattern 1 - Left Aligned" appear in the console window, if not then you need to enter some value and press enter.

Comment: Why whts wrong in the style...

Comment: @Tuhin: well ... mixing flow-logic with ui-specific commands: not a good idea to call `Console`-methods inside - that should be a parameter of `pattern`-method ... using instance-variables means not being multi-threading safe - even if that is not what you want: don't do that except you design your classes properly! basically what you do is called spaghetti/ravioli/lasagna-code

Comment: @Andreas: see i am new to OOP,and am not exactly sure what you are talking about,so could you kindly give some code samples ...

Comment: @Tuhin: well, if you are new to OOP, i'm sure you will make your way. your code violates some serious paradigms. just remember to separate each logical layer: talking to the UI is something completely different than looping with a value (which might be retrieved from the UI). it's not about OOP-style only, it's about design-patterns as well (oh sh*t, i hate that thing) - simply: design ... a good point to start would be following thought: "what if i should fix/enhance that code ... which obstacles did i just put in my way"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're redeclaring `n` as a local variable in `getData()`.

Try changing that line to:

```
 n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

i.e. remove the `int`.

Comment: +1: Looks to me like it should actually be throwing a compilation error or warning for a redeclaration of a variable within nested scopes.

Comment: @Joel: why a compiler error? ... nope ... the instance-variable will not be assigned and will be left with its default value 0 ... a warning ... yes!

Comment: @Tuhin: if this answer is what you need, you should accept it!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: I just remember the VS IDE would mark it as something. I couldn't remember if it was a warning or an error, and since I'm currently avoiding a business requirements review I didn't want to waste the time to verify. I figured someone who did remember right away would comment :)

Comment: @Joel :) ... and yes, you are right: it gets underlined as well!

Answer (score 1):

well ...

as you are not using `this`...

```
class Myclass
{
    int i, n, j;

    public void getData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program for displaying pattern of *.");
        Console.Write("Enter the maximum number of *: ");
        this.n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        // OR
        //n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void pattern()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPattern 1 - Left Aligned:\n");
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)  // The Control does not enter the for loop
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                Console.Write("*");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

i would encourage you to use `this` to distinct between scope- and instance-variables!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to assign n using Console.ReadLine() in getData(), you need to remove the "int" just before.  Currently, you have 2 "n" variable in different scopes.  That's why your loop doesn't work.